# AWS Lambda - node app split into multiple lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Usually when I deploy my app to AWS Lambda it is still one self-contained app which resolves requests inside of it.

So no matter what request I send, full lambda starts and handles this request:

[image]

I know that some people take full advantage of lambdas and deploy each "endpoint" as individual lambda function like this:

[image]

How do you run this locally? To me it seems like you would have to run as many node apps as many endpoints you have.

Are there any frameworks/methods which help with such architecture?
Maybe something would be able to "extract" all endpoints from a node app and build lambdas for each of them?